# Querying variant data in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten, variant, querying

Here is the data variant source table I am using in my example. I want to make a query to parse this data into a table in snowflake from a variant src.

```
{
    "col1": bool,
    "col2": null,
    "col3": "datetime",
    "col4": int,
    "col5": "string",
    "col6": "string",
    "array": [
        {
            "x": bool,
            "y": null,
            "v": "datetime",
            "z": int,
           "w": "string",
            "q": "string",
            "obj": {
                    "a": "bool",
                     "b": "float"
                   },
    "col7": "datetime"
}
]
}
```

-- Here what I tried

```
SELECT 

     src:col1::string as col1,
     src:col2::string as col2,
     src:col3::string as col3,
     src:col4::string as col4,
     src:col5::string as col5,
     src:col6::string as col6,

     s.value:x::string as S_x,
     s.value:y::string as s_y,
     s.value:v::string as s_v,
     s.value:z::string as s_z,
     s.value:w::string as s_w,
     s.value:q::string as s_q,

     s.value:obj.value:a::string as s_obj_a,
     s.value:obj.value:b::string as s_obj_b,

     src:col7::string as col7 
FROM tblvariant
    , table(flatten(src:s)) s
    ;
```

Everything is working except that these two columns (a, b) are null while they should contain their data.
Any suggestion?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> s.value:obj **.value:a** ::string as s_obj_a,
>
> s.value:obj **.value:b** ::string as s_obj_b,

Accessing an object's keys can be done with the use of the [dot (`.`) notation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-semistructured.html#dot-notation). You do not need to use the [`GET_PATH` (`:`) operator](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_path.html) to gain access to those fields:

```sql
s.value:metadata.a::string as s_m_a,
s.value:metadata.b::string as s_m_b,
```

You also do not need to run a second [`FLATTEN`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html) over the `metadata` object within your `stages` array, unless you truly need one exclusive row per `metadata` key, assuming `metadata` is an object type and not a nested array. If you just want to extract the values out into the same level as each array row, just using the above should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Your sample JSON does not match with your SQL. Where are "stages" and "metadata"? Anyway, the problem seems about extra "value" keyword.

```
create or replace table tblvariant ( src variant )
as select parse_json (' 
{
    "col1": "bool",
    "col2": null,
    "col3": "datetime",
    "col4": "int",
    "col5": "string",
    "col6": "string",
    "stages": [
        {
            "x": "bool",
            "y": null,
            "v": "datetime",
            "z": "int",
           "w": "string",
            "q": "string",
            "obj": {
                    "a": "bool",
                     "b": "float"
                   },
    "col7": "datetime"
}
]
}' );
```

As you see, I modified your sample JSON and renamed "array" to "stages" (according to your SQL). This SQL retrieves values of a and b:

```
SELECT 
     src:col1::string as col1,
     src:col2::string as col2,
     src:col3::string as col3,
     src:col4::string as col4,
     src:col5::string as col5,
     src:col6::string as col6,
     s.value:x::string as S_x,
     s.value:y::string as s_y,
     s.value:v::string as s_v,
     s.value:z::string as s_z,
     s.value:w::string as s_w,
     s.value:q::string as s_q,

     s.value:obj.a::string as s_obj_a,
     s.value:obj.b::string as s_obj_b,

     src:col7::string as col7 
FROM tblvariant
   , table(flatten(src:stages)) s
   -- , table(flatten(s.value:metadata)) m
    ;
```